# OpenVPN: No internet when connected (Mac)

Tags: mac, dns, openvpn

I installed the OpenVPN client on my MAC. When connecting there is no internet.

Here is what I have observed:

- On other clients (Android) it works with the same OpenVPN server
- When I go to network settings and change something randomly (for example the sort order of network modules without changing it) and then click the apply button -> it then suddenly works. But only on Chrome, not on Firefox. After reconnecting it again doesn't work
- Same happens when I use Tunnelblick and set DNS/WINS to "set namserver 3.0b10". Only works on Chrome here permanently.

I tried a lot like flushing the DNS cache, reinstalling the client. Compressions is disabled. I am running out of ideas. Any help? Thx